# Not possible to add feature to Shapefile

Tags: qgis, editing

While in editing mode of an already existing layer, the "add feature" button is not enabled. However, it is possible to add a circular feature, move feature, etc.

What can I do to have the button enabled again?

Comment: are you working with shapefiles or a database layer?

Comment: with a shapefile, I also have other shapefiles in that project but no problem with those, so it seems to come from the shp itself

Comment: Would be useful add some screenshots

Comment: of properties of layer?

Comment: Make sure that you have permission to edit the layer's source file. In Windows, go to the source file, right click on file > Security tab > Permissions. If shapefile, check this for every component (.dbf, .shp, etc.). Also note that some layer types cannot be edited if the layer is filtered.